# Spark Cluster Standalone

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing

I have a Spark Cluster of 1 Driver and 1 Worker where both servers have the same specs (8vCore and 32GB Ram, 600GB SSD)

I have followed several guides to install and configure the cluster and I have Hadoop (version 2.7.3) and Spark (version 2.4.6). I know both Spark and Hadoop are working

However when I do the following:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("alma_v2").master("spark://master:7077").getOrCreate()
```

(I have tried both with spark://master:7077 and spark://ip-of-master:7077

and then do any action, such as a read of a DataFrame from HDFS or create a DataFrame and .show() it I get the following message

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I have the following screenshot of the SparkUI

[image]

I can quickly notice my process is using all the 8 vCores and 1024 MB of RAM, even though I haven't run anything. I also have checked if the default ports are open, and they all are on both Driver and Worker.

Why is it saying my cluster doesn't have sufficient resources? How can I fix this?

Thank you,

EDIT:

I have tried now several configurations, to limit the amount of memory, cores used both by the driver and executors. However I have noticed the following:

New executors keep being created every seconds, and they keep being killed for some reason. I'm guessing because of the error?

The configs I have tried are the following:

```
.config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false").config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false").config("spark.executor.instances", "2").config("spark.executor.cores", "2").config("spark.executor.memory", "2g").config("spark.driver.memory", "5g").config("spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors", "2").config("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors","2").config("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors","2").config("spark.driver.cores","2").config("spark.cores.max","2").config("spark.task.cpus","1")
```

[image]